# WkWebViewの広告ブロックについて

Tags: javascript, swift, ios

UIWebViewからWkWebViewでの移行で、それまではUIWebViewではURLProtocolを用いて、Webページの広告をブロックしていましたが、WkWebViewではそれが動きません。そこで、WkWebViewの設定で下記のようにJavaScript自体をoffにして、広告ブロックすることが出来ました。しかしながら、広告をブロックするためにJavaScript自体をoffにするのは、少し乱暴な気がします。

```
let preferences = WKPreferences()
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false    // javascriptをoffにする。
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.preferences = preferences
```

そこで、調べた結果下記のユーザースクリプトを使って、JavaScriptを実行して広告をoffにすることができることがわかりました。

```
let userScript1 = WKUserScript(source: "", injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)

    let controller = WKUserContentController()
    controller.addUserScript(userScript1)

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController = controller
```

WKUserScriptのsource部分にどのようなJavaScriptを書けば広告をブロックすることが出来るかを教えて下さい。また、これらの方法以外に良い広告ブロック方法を教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: 広告のDOM要素を非表示にしたり消したりはできるかもしれませんが、UserScriptで通信をフィルタすることはできないはずです。その方法で広告をブロックすることができるという情報はどこで聞いたのでしょうか？参考にされた記事のURLなどがあれば質問に追記してもらえませんか？

Comment: 色々と調べているうちに広告を消すという点でURLProtocolとUserScriptの挙動を混同していました。あらかじめUserScriptを使って広告を非表示にするには、どのようなJavaScriptのコードを書けば良いかという質問です。わかりにく質問で申し訳ありません。JavaScript自体をoffにすると広告も消えますが、youtube等も見れなくなり困っています。どのようなコードを書けば良いか教えて頂けると幸いです。ご指摘ありがとうございました。